# Redirecting to a page using IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a site .net 2.0 and I redirected users to a
login page when the hit the site. (I think the default.aspx page)

But i cant remember how i did it.

I am now wanting upgrade to asp.net mvc app
but the redirect is still there to a nonexistent page.

Any ideas how to find the redirect?

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Use [WireShark Network Analyzer](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to find out what type of Redirect you have and the location that's redirecting.

You can then use IIS management console to see if there are any redirects in the site or virtual directory properties.

And finally check the source of the script that handles the request for *Response.Redirect()* or *Server.Transfer()*.